# Can WordPress Be Installed on a Subdomain of Existing Site?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, website-design

I have a Web Design and Linux Development site `example.com` and a subdomain howto page for Debian minimal install instructions, `subdomain.example.com`

I want to add another subdomain with WordPress installed for a friend's non-profit. I've manually installed WordPress before, but never as a subdomain.

Comment: Yes... you can but what type of answer/information are you expecting? since a guide would be too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WordPress can be installed on a subdomain - in fact it might be the most common way to use WordPress. Just input your custom subdomain name instead of the usual `www` subdomain when you set up the install.

For DNS all you should need is one `A` or `CNAME` record, which won't affect your main domain or any of your other subdomains.